# I tried to browse websites with Tor but all I get are "Unable to find the proxy server" error pages.

Tags: mac, proxy

I am a new user of Tor and have downloaded the newest version for macintosh. I have the latest OSX and a good working computer. The installation went well and the browser physically looks normal.

However I tried to search any sites and I am greeted with a blank webpage with an error stating "Unable to find the proxy server". I have tried a multiple suggestions from Youtube but they did not help.

Any help would be much appreciated. I tried changing the network connection settings (In Preferences>Advanced>Network>Connections>Settings) to "no proxy" or "Auto-detect proxy settings for this network" but neither worked. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Did you use the Tor Browser? Which version did you install? If not, what did you install and how have you configured it?

Comment: Thats because you are not connected to tor network.
Check your configurations and connection to tor network. Possible fixes:- Try to reconnect to tor.
flush all the proxy rules.
Reboot your device.

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this, this just started to happen to me also. It was working fine. No changes were made, no updates, no nothing. Quit the browser, restarted computer same thing. New Mac Book Pro Running Sierra. FireFox and other browsers work fine.

Comment: Simple way to fix the "UNABLE TO FIND THE PROXY SERVER" is **disable** the "noscript" from the add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

From the unedited original question: are you using Tor browser or Tor by itself  (It is a software that *only* helps you to connect to a Tor circuit)? I will recommend that you should use **[Tor browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)** than to use Tor by itself.

Because the tor browser settings has been configured to be identical with other downloaded Tor browser bundle so that you have the same browser fingerprint as all other Tor browser users. If you are using any other browsers on top of just Tor alone, your browser fingerprint will probably be unique and adversaries will use it to identify you even though your connection is through a Tor circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-detection is used via WPAD/PAC files on routers, so it won't work on any platform. Set up manually SOCKS proxy. I do recommend Firefox and FoxyProxy addon. Also you can use other browsers if they do support SOCKS *properly*. If the problem is with SOCKS - try using polipo to make HTTP proxy interface available